# How to use predefined chrome profile in selenium for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have several custom profile in my chrome browser. for example i want to use "test 2" profile to be used in my selenium. (see the picture below)

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYcG8.png

This is the code i see from the internet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

How can i use the "test 2" profile? Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need add one more argument:

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
```

`Profile 1` - is a directory of your profile and its name is not like a profile name. You can explore all the profile direstories in your `user-data-dir`. How to find out what dir is the dir for "test 2" profile - you can find here https://superuser.com/a/723145