# How to create chrome profile using selenium for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I intend to create profile in my chrome using selenium for python.

[image]

I haven't found any documentation related to this topic. 
I would really appreciate for your help. Thank You.

Comment: Take a look at this link and let us know if what you are asking is beyond this information. 
 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/854

Comment: @JosephK. I want to create a new profile. Not using the existing one.

Comment: ok, i've no chrome in my desktop, but I know lot of chrome's configuration pages are accessible via url (don't remember but urls like: chrome://something/somethingelse). You can try to create a profile within a classic chrome browser and check if you have urls. If yes, you can make selenium browse chrome configs to create a new profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use predefined chrome profile in selenium for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901696/how-to-use-predefined-chrome-profile-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: @EugeneS nope. that question only for "using profile that have already exist in chrome with selenium". what i want is to "create new profile using selenium". not manually go to setting -> manage other people -> add person. i want to create hundreds of profile.